# How do you call a javaScript function inside a Django template?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I want to call the `javaScript` function defined inside the same template in Django. How can I do it?

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

        {% if error %}
            showAlert()
        {% endif %}

    <script> function showAlert() {alert ("Please select at least one option");}</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to call `showAlert()` if there is `error` present. I have handled the `error` in the view. I do not a method about how to call the function here? It is showing the function name.

Comment: Bear in mind that the template is rendered on the server using Python; `alert` is available in the browser in JavaScript.

Comment: Oh! yeah!! Got it.....  but how can I do this? Loading a JS file or what else?

Comment: You're already showing how to use JavaScript - `<script>` blocks.

Comment: But how am I supposed to call this? This is not working....

Comment: if you open the browser console, you may see an error like "ReferenceError: showAlert is not defined", just move the definition of the function on top. and also call `<script> showAlert() </script>`

Comment: I did it earlier but the problem is that the page does not load until I press Ok on the the alert. That's why I moved it

Comment: maybe a popup alert is not the best, but you can also delay the opening with : `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    alert ("Please select at least one option");
}, false);`

Answer (score 2):

You can call the javascript function inside the `<script>` tag

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <script> 
      function showAlert() {
            alert ("Please select at least one option");
      }
    </script>

    {% if error %}
    <script>
        showAlert()
    </script>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Or you can put `{% if ... %}` statement inside `<script>` tag

Comment: Thanks for helping out buddy but the problem is that it does not let the page to load until clicked okay.